# bash script, line 30: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I`v wrote some script, and have unexpected end of file

```
echo off
if [$JAVA_HOME = ""]; then goto no_java_home fi
if [$SRV_HOME = ""]; then  goto no_srv_home fi
echo Uses JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME
echo Uses SRV_HOME=$SRV_HOME
export ACP=""
export ACP=$ACP;$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
export ACP=$ACP;$SRV_HOME/ant/lib/ant.jar
export ACP=$ACP;$SRV_HOME/ant/lib/ant-launcher.jar
export ACP=$ACP;$SRV_HOME/ant/lib/ant-nodeps.jar
export ACP=$ACP;$SRV_HOME/ant/lib/optional.jar
export ACP=$ACP;$SRV_HOME/ant/lib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -Xmx512m -classpath $ACP org.apache.tools.ant.Main -buildfile $SRV_HOME/ant/ant_script.xml %*
goto ends

no_srv_home:
clear
echo "You should set the TMX_HOME environment variable. For example: TMX_HOME=d:\MYSERVER"
goto ends

no_java_home:
clear
echo "You should set the JAVA_HOME environment variable"
goto ends
ends: echo "OK"
```

Where is my problem?

Comment: Bash doesn't have `goto` or `echo off` and you have to put a space after `[` and before `]`. You may not need to `export` the `ACP` variable since it is being passed as an argument (does Java look for it in its environment?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that your script looks like a haphazard mix of bash and cmd syntax. Here's a bash script.

```
if [ "$JAVA_HOME" = "" ]; then
  echo 1>&2 "$0: You need to set the JAVA_HOME variable, e.g.: export JAVA_HOME='c:/java'"
  exit 2
fi
if [ "$SRV_HOME" = "" ]; then
  echo 1>&2 "$0: You need to set the SRV_HOME variable, e.g.: export SRV_HOME='d:/myserver'"
  exit 2
fi
echo "$0: Uses JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME"
echo "$0: Uses SRV_HOME=$SRV_HOME"
ACP="$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar"
for x in ant ant-launcher ant-nodeps optional ant-contrib-1.0b3; do
  ACP="$ACP;$SRV_HOME/ant/lib/$x.jar"
done
"$JAVA_HOME/bin/java" -Xmx512m -classpath "$ACP" \
                      org.apache.tools.ant.Main \
                      -buildfile "$SRV_HOME/ant/ant_script.xml" \
                      "$@"
```

Here's a list of things I've corrected:

- Bash has structured programming constructs (blocks, conditionals, loops). It doesn't have goto.
- The test command `[ … ]` requires spaces on each side of the brackets (except with punctuation like `;`).
- All variable substitutions (`$foo`) should be in double quotes (otherwise the shell will do strange things if the value of the variable contains certain special characters such as spaces).
- Error messages should be displayed on the error output: `echo 1>&2 "this is an error message"`. (This would apply to a cmd script as well.)
- If an error occurs, the script should return a non-zero status. (This would apply to a cmd script as well.)
- Since `ACP` is an internal script variable, there is no need to export it into the environment.
- `;` is a special character, so it must be quoted when you want to use it in a string.
- (Optional) You can avoid repeating the same string many times with a loop (loops in bash don't have the crazy limitations they have in cmd).
- Cmd's `%*` is bash's `"$@"`.
- (Optional) If your script is called by another script which is called etc, it's nice to have the script name `$0` in each error message.
- (Optional) You can break a long command line with a backslash at the end of the line.

Answer (score 2):

Goto, really?

Alter your if statements to add a semi-colon before fi

```
if [$JAVA_HOME = ""]; then goto no_java_home ; fi
```

for example.

Your shell is unable to distinguish between the no_java_home command and the fi command because they appeared on the same line without a semi-colon delimiter or anything else that would end a statement. You have the same problem on your lines with clear echo; as far as `sh` is concerned echo here is used as an argument to clear and is not a separate command.

But please, rewrite this without using goto!

Like this:

```
if [$JAVA_HOME = ""] ; then
        clear
        echo "You should set the JAVA_HOME environment variable"
elif [$SRV_HOME = ""] ; then
        clear
        echo "You should set the TMX_HOME environment variable. For example: TMX_HOME=d:\MYSERVER"
else
        echo Uses JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME

        echo Uses SRV_HOME=$SRV_HOME

        export ACP=""

        export ACP=$ACP;$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar

        export ACP=$ACP;$SRV_HOME/ant/lib/ant.jar

        export ACP=$ACP;$SRV_HOME/ant/lib/ant-launcher.jar

        export ACP=$ACP;$SRV_HOME/ant/lib/ant-nodeps.jar

        export ACP=$ACP;$SRV_HOME/ant/lib/optional.jar

        export ACP=$ACP;$SRV_HOME/ant/lib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar

        $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -Xmx512m -classpath $ACP org.apache.tools.ant.Main -buildfile

        $SRV_HOME/ant/ant_script.xml %*
fi

echo "OK"
```

Answer (score 0):

If I rewrite the following lines differently, the unexpected end of file error goes off.

Original line:

```
if [$JAVA_HOME = ""]; then goto no_java_home fi    
if [$SRV_HOME = ""]; then goto no_srv_home fi
```

Updated:

```
if [$JAVA_HOME = ""]; then 
  goto no_java_home 
fi

if [$SRV_HOME = ""]; then 
  goto no_srv_home 
fi
```